# JavaScript confirm Okay button not calling server side method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Confirm okay button is not working, its not calling server side method.

Buttons get disabled but server side function is not being called.

If i remove the following two lines from the confirm method then it works fine;

```
      document.getElementById('btnSubmit').disabled = true;
      document.getElementById('btnCancel').disabled = true;
```

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<script language="javascript">

    function confirmPayment() {

        var isOkay = confirm("Confirm Payment?");

        if (isOkay) {
            document.getElementById('btnSubmit').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('btnCancel').disabled = true;
         
            return isOkay;
        } else {
            return isOkay;
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"  Width="110px" OnClientClick="return confirmPayment();" 
                Text="Submit Payment" ></asp:Button>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server"  Width="110px"
                Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="False"></asp:Button>
</div>
</form>

</body>
```

any thoughts ?

Comment: There is no `.attr()` method. You're confusing jQuery APIs with DOM APIs.

Comment: sorry i put the wrong code. i have updated my question

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for other errors? Also doesn't ASP create weird element IDs for you?

Comment: no errors on browser console

Comment: what happens if you type `document.getElementById('btnSubmit')` in the console? In reference to Pointy comment above

Comment: in your `OnClientClick` there's a typo error of `retuen`, change it to `return`

Comment: it is return, it was typo.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a server side method set on btnSubmit. There is no onClick only onClientClick

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you set the controls ClientIDMode="Static" just in case.

If you don't do this, then you should adopt this format:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>');
```

Or in your case:

```
document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>).disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set timeout 0 has done the trick.

function confirmPayment() {

```
            var isOkay = confirm("Confirm Payment?");

            if (isOkay) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    document.getElementById('btnSubmit').innerText = 'Processing...';
                    document.getElementById('btnSubmit').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('btnCancel').disabled = true;
                }, 0);
         
                return isOkay;
            } else {
                //event.preventDefault();
                return isOkay;
            }
        }
```